# Using <f:convertDateTime> with <h:commandLink>

Tags: jsf, datetime, commandlink

I saw this example provided by BalusC:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.calendar.time}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="long" />
</h:outputText>
```

How is that working with <`h:commandLink>` ?

I tried:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{question.creationDate.time}"
    action="#{managerBean.searchQuestion()}">
  <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" />
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{managerBean.questionID}"
    value="#{question.ID}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `<h:outputText>` inside `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{managerBean.searchQuestion}">
    <h:outputText value="#{question.creationDate.time}">
        <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" />
    </h:outputText>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{managerBean.questionID}" value="#{question.ID}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I did not expect, that I could use <h:outputText> in <:hcommandLink>.